# VBA vlookup for multiple columns

Tags: vba, vlookup

I am trying to compare two tables of data on the same sheets and display matches in a 3rd table. I can get the first column in the 3rd table to return matches however the other matches don't display all the results or any results at all. Below is the code I have so far, a link to the screen shot of the tables. I am very new to VBA any info would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub CarrierNameMatch()
On Error Resume Next

For m = 3 To 100

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(m, 13).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(m, 8).Value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:D"), 1, 0)

Next

End Sub
Sub CarrierSCACMatch()

On Error Resume Next

For n = 3 To 100

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 14).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 9).Value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:D"), 2, 0)

Next

End Sub
Sub CarrierMCMatch()

On Error Resume Next

For o = 3 To 100

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(o, 15).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(o, 10).Value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:D"), 3, 0)

Next
End Sub
Sub CarrierDotMatch()

On Error Resume Next

For p = 3 To 100

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(p, 16).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(p, 11).Value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:D"), 4, 0)

Next

End Sub
```

[Sheet table info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T6fB.png)

Comment: the first criteria in each vlookup would need to always be: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(m, 8).Value` it should not change the reference.

Comment: For each column I am looking up a different cell. For example I am looking to match Column H, to Column A and put the results in Column N. Then looking to match Column i to column B and put the results in Column N and so on. I tried your change and I dont get any results

Comment: Then you need to change the search range to include the first column as the lookup column.  Right now it is always looking in column A and returning the column value dictated by the third criterion.

Comment: That makes sense, I am getting values as long as I get a match in Column A. Can you please send me an example to change my search from a cell to a range?